# SQL statement athena

Tags: sql

I have been trying to run this SQL query in athena and I keep getting this error:

> line 2:17: mismatched input 'BY'. Expecting: ',',

I have looked over this for so long and I have no idea why my partition by statement is wrong.

My query:

```
select 
    from_unixtime(timestamp) as event_time, 
    upper(device) as device, 
    resource, observation,
    over (partition by metric order by field(metric, 'Processor Usage')) as Processor_Usage
from 
    table1
where 
    from_unixtime(timestamp) > cast('2022-03-12 00:00:00' as timestamp)
    and substr(device, 4, 1) in ('3', '5')
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking *SQL statement athena* is useless, as it provides no information. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your current title provides zero information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an aggregation in your windowing column, you want something like `SUM()` or `COUNT()` in front of the `OVER`.